# NHibernate - fetch class by criteria over two item in an inner collection

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a class (Invoice) with a collection (InvoiceRows).

Classes -

```
public class Invoice
{
     public string ID {get; set;}
     public List<InvoiceRow> InvoiceRows {get; set;}
}

public class InvoiceRow
{
    public string ID { get; set;}
    public string InvoiceID { get; set;}
    public int RowNumber { get; set;}
}
```

Mappings -

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
   <class name="Domain.BusinessClasses.Invoice" table="Invoices" lazy="false">
     <id name="ID">
       <column name="ID"/>
       <generator class="assigned"/>
     </id>
     <bag name="InvoiceRows" lazy="false" cascade="save-update" inverse="true" order-by="InvoiceRowNumber">
       <key column="InvoiceID"/>
       <one-to-many class="Domain.BusinessClasses.InvoiceRow" />
     </bag>
   </class>

   <class name="Domain.BusinessClasses.InvoiceRow" table="InvoiceRows" lazy="false">
     <id name="ID">
       <column name="ID"/>
       <generator class="assigned"/>
     </id>
     <property name="InvoiceID">
       <column name="InvoiceID"/>
     </property>
     <property name="RowNumber">
       <column name="RowNumber"/>
     </property>
   </class>
```

I want to get all the Invoice objects that have an InvoiceRow with RowNumber = 1 **and** RowNumber = 2. Preferably with ICriterion API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find the answer based on [Genius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/327853/genius) answer.

```
    var dCriteria1 = DetachedCriteria.For<InvoiceRow>("r")
            .SetProjection(Projections.Property("r.RowNumber"))
            .SetProjection(Projections.Property("r.InvoiceID")) // Must be last!!!!
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("r.RowNumber", 1));

    var dCriteria2 = DetachedCriteria.For<InvoiceRow>("r")
            .SetProjection(Projections.Property("r.RowNumber"))
            .SetProjection(Projections.Property("r.InvoiceID")) // Must be last!!!!
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("r.RowNumber", 2));


    var invoices = Session.CreateCriteria<Invoice>()
            .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("ID", dCriteria1))
            .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("ID", dCriteria2))          
            .List<Invoice>();
```

Answer (score 2):

should look like this (not checked!):

```
var dCriteria1 = DetachedCriteria.For<InvoiceRow>("r")
        .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("r.InvoiceID", "i.ID"))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("r.RowNumber", 1));
var dCriteria2 = DetachedCriteria.For<InvoiceRow>("r")
        .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("r.InvoiceID", "i.ID"))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("r.RowNumber", 2));

var invoices = Session.CreateCriteria<Invoice>("i")
   .Add(Subqueries.Exists(dCriteria1))
   .Add(Subqueries.Exists(dCriteria2))
   .List<Invoice>();
```

may be this code can be optimized, but idea is such.

Comment: I'm having some troubles implementing this, some kind of projections problem. Could you please be a little more specific?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> list=new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
DetachedCriteria forInvoice=DetachedCriteria.For<Invoice>();
DetachedCriteria forInvoiceRow=forInvoice.CreateCriteria("InvoiceRows");
forInvoiceRow.Add(Expression.In("RowNumber",list));
ICriteria executableCriteria = forInvoice.GetExecutableCriteria(Session);
executableCriteria.List<Invoice>();
```